# How to edit Product name in Magento Admin in Sales order tab ( Information , Invoices , Credit Memos , Shipments ) and in its email as well

Tags: magento2, product, admin, orders, sales

How to edit Product name in Magento Admin in Sales order tab ( Information, Invoices, Credit Memos, Shipments ) and in its email as well.

Like I want to append some data in Name but didn't get the file to edit and for email as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully extended that using XML file.

These are the files which i have used to extend that in my custom module.

File Path are you package path then view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_order_shipment_new.xml

```
adminhtml_order_shipment_new , adminhtml_order_shipment_view , sales_order_creditmemo_new , sales_order_creditmemo_view , sales_order_invoice_view , sales_order_view
```